# MySQL set default field value on delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query. I have 2 tables with relationship.

```
  table category
  CategoryId       name   
      1          category1
      2          category2


  table order
  orderId          CategoryId             date         Description
     1                 2               2014-10-10         okay
     2                 1               2014-10-10         okay2
     3                 1               2014-10-10         okay3
```

my question is how to set categoryname if one of category have deleted.

Comment: Set it to what? When what's deleted? You probably want to do this in your application code, not purely in the database, but if you're crazy enough to go that way, you want to set up a trigger.

Comment: @tadman set default value to 'n/a', when category have deleted from table category

Comment: Do you have a properly set foreign key between categrory.categoryId and order.categoryId ? BTW, order is a BAD name for a table (order is a reserved word).

Answer (score 1):

The most important question here is about the business logic.  Does an order without a category make sense?  If yes, then you can set the `categoryId` to `null` in the `orders` table when a category is deleted.  You can use triggers for that.

However a better solution would be to add `enabled` column to your category and instead of deleting a category simply set its `enabled` to `false` - this makes it unavailable for further selection yet preserves the previous information/relationship.  Of course, this would require a small change in the place where the categories are selected for presentation, namely adding `where enabled=true` to the query.

If you're set on deleting the category and settings category ID to null in the orders, then the syntax you're looking for is

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER category_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON category FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE `order` SET categoryid=null WHERE categoryid=OLD.categoryid;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```